# Mixed Distribution and Convex Combination

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

[image]

I am very new to this topic and I am trying to figure out the concept behind the sentence 'P is a convex combination....', particularly I do not understand the term E(\lambda) in the expression.

Comment: But why is that g(t)= E_{\lambda}(t) in this case, is it referring to the expected value of random variable t or pdf of t when  0 <= t <s

Comment: I take it back.  I would ignore that last sentence they write, it seems incorrect: That function is not really a convex combination of CDFs.  I don't love the notation of the book either:  Usually $F_P(t)$ would be used as the CDF of a random variable $P$.  A true convex combination of the CDF for a constant random variable $C=s$ and the CDF for an exponential random variable $X \sim exp(\lambda)$ would be $\theta F_C(t) + (1-\theta) F_X(t)$ for some $\theta \in [0,1]$.  You can try to use $\theta = e^{-\lambda s}$, but it is not the same as the function they give.